# Laravel validation double nested

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I'm having issues with double nested validation

My form is rather large and contains some nested data. Two of the fields:

```
{!! Form::text('address[city]', null, [] !!}
{!! Form::text('address[country[printable_name]]', null, [] )) !!}
```

For example this works:

```
'address.city' => 'required|max:255',
```

but

```
'address.country.printable_name' => 'required|max:255|country
```

throws "*The address.country.printable name field is required.*" even though it has a valid country.

If I try to print all with $request->all() I get the following:

```
...,"address":{"city":"Maribor","country[printable_name":"Slovenia"},...
```

So there is missing `]` after printable_name.

If I try to print

```
$request->input('address.country.printable_name')
```

I don't get anything, but it works when I try this:

```
$request->input('address')["country[printable_name"]
```

Did I do something wrong, is this not supported in Laravel or a bug? Either way, how can I get it work?

A workaround would be this

```
'boat.country[printable_name' => 'required|max:255',
```

but if I leave this the next developer to look at the code will probably want to kick my ass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to nest array items in request parameters you should do it like this:

```
{!! Form::text('address[country][printable_name]', null, []) !!}
```

Then you can access them as you've initially tried:

```
$request->input('address.country.printable_name')
```

---

Just think of structuring it as you would access it in an associative array in PHP. If you pass a parameter with this name in your form:

```
address[country][printable_name]
```

Then using plain PHP you would access it like this:

```
$_REQUEST['address']['country']['printable_name'];
```

The above example illustrates the equivalent structure.

Comment: Try it, address.country.printable_name won't return anything. I know it should, but it doesn't.

Comment: Well what is the output of `dump($request->all())` after you've made the change I've suggested?

Comment: Sorry, made a typo when I first tried your way. Works like a charm. Thanks!